# Visual Studio 19 Xamarin Bug - "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I've recently decided to embark on Xamarin development, but after 5 days mucking about with 2 PCs and not getting anywhere, I installed VS2019 on another machine and everything seemed to be working until I attempted to create a new Xamarin project (on a Windows 10 build1903 machine).

The steps are:

1. Open Visual Studio 2019
2. Create New Project
3. Select "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)"
4. Pick a name (or get a default name like App1)
5. Click Create
6. Select any Template (like "Blank")
7. Check/Uncheck what ever types (I usually just check "Android")
8. Click the Create button.
9. Wait for about 10 seconds (VS is in "Creating Project" mode)
10. The message "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the
    requested service" is displayed and you can go no further.

What I've tried (based on recommendations):
Run VS as Administrator
Disabled all startup services
Completely uninstalled my antivirus program
Completely disabled the firewall
Ran Disk Scan on both drives (no errors)
Ran full memory test on system (a 2 hour rigorous test)
Disabled System Restore
Changed paging size to 16000 (from system managed size)
Changed paging disk locations

Nothing worked.
All other project types work just fine (no errors).
16GB of memory - and while observing with processExplorer, only about 4GB was being utilized, no memory errors in log, no paging errors (plenty of drive space - 900GB + )

Because only the Xamarin project is affected, I uninstalled that from VS installer, then reinstalled it: No Joy.
I can run dozens of programs simultaneously on this PC including Office, multiple browsers with 90% memory utilization and never get this error, so this has to be some compatibility with Visual Studio 2019 and Windows 10 (worked under Windows 8.1 perfectly but I require the Win10-Only features).

No useful help from Microsoft forums and I've scoured SO for any solutions. I just want to learn Xamarin, but 5 days and 3 PCs later, it's just not happening.

Comment: What is the age of your drivers may I ask?

Comment: Have you tried to repair this VS?

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with the user profile (the one I was on was 94GB in size - that may be what was wrong).  No idea what, but I created a new profile and everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

After logging in as a different user and discovering it worked, I narrowed the problem down to the user profile.
Apparently, the user profile was corrupted in a way that was undetectable via DISM and SFC or any tool on the Internet I tried.
I ended up creating a new user profile and copied the old stuff into it (except a bunch of files that I moved to separate folders to cut down on the giant profile size of 94GB down to about 30GB).  Ran VS as before and was able to create a new Xamarin project without the resource error.